# Cmd need to be reset

Tags: windows, conemu, cmd.exe

I have played around with ConEmu

But something has happened when is started C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe it says:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]
(c) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. 

Cannot find path specified
C:\Users\Lucas>
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: It seems that you do not supply enough details. For example how do you start ConEmu (with which parameters)?

Comment: I don't start conemu, i start the cmd Console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like cmd was started normally, but some problem was occurred while cmd is processing your `AutoRun` command. Check your registry

```
[HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor]
"Autorun"=...
[HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor]
"Autorun"=...
```

I believe, one of this values contains some bad paths.

Comment: It was the problem, Autorun was located to far manager, but do i leave it blank or do i need to type something in? Ps i know i should not say this but thank you so very much you saved me.

Comment: Very bad form, that someone (installer or you) was set `AutoRun` to such application as Far manager. You may delete this value or set it to empty string. Does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the path doesn't exist or the emulator can't access that folder due to permission settings.

I assume the former is at fault. As such, try to run the program in admin mode.

For reference this is the project's webpage ([ConEmu](http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/)).

Looking through the project's FAQ a similar problem exists. Quoting both the question and the answer:

> Q. After running the commands start, echo (and other cmd.exe commands) on 64-bit systems, an error similar to "File not found. Cannot execute. start" appears
>
> A. This is most likely caused by the absence of ConEmuC64.exe and accompanying ConEmuHk64.dll, ConEmuCD64.dll.

Comment: It is not the ConEmu i need help with, it is the real cmd window. Because everytime i start the command: CMD it says the copyright, the file can not be found and at last the output.